# Запрос permission на отправку Push Notification

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-permissions

Могу ли я запрашивать `permission` на отправку `Push Notification` по аналогии с локацией или доступом к памяти?

[В документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY) нашел описание `ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY`, но не уверен что это именно то что мне нужно!

Для теста попробовал сделать запрос:

```
requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY},100);
```

но никакого диалогового окна не увидил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так `ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY` имеет `protection level: normal`. Если мне память не изменяет, то normal пермишены в тихую выдаются без появления окна.

Это, во-первых.

Во-вторых, для пушей никаких пермишенов не нужно вовсе.

Можете ещё [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43123650/1991579) ответ посмотреть.